# seek method RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, seek, randomaccessfile, file-pointer

I have an assignment where I need to display 200 random characters and then ask the use what letter they would like to replace and then replace all those letters. I have the random characters generated, but I am having trouble with replacing the letters. Can someone help lead me in the right direction? Here are some other questions i have:

- Do I use a for loop for the seek method so it will find all those letters?
- I also need to display the position each of the letters. Would I use filepointer and would I put that in a loop as well?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alphabet {
    public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));
    }

    public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter() {
        return getRandomCharacter('A', 'Z');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("Alphabet.dat", "rw")) {
            raf.setLength(0);

            for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row){
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; ++col) {
                    raf.writeChar(getRandomUpperCaseLetter());
                }
            }

            raf.seek(0);
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row){
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; ++col) {
                    System.out.print(raf.readChar() +" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            Scanner Console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Current length of file is: "
                    + raf.length());
            System.out.print("Replace Characters: ");
            String letter = Console.next();
            System.out.print("With Character: ");
            String ch = Console.next();

                for(int j = 0; j < raf.length(); ++j){
                    raf.seek((raf.length()-1)*2);
                    raf.writeChars(ch);
                    System.out.print("Position" + raf.getFilePointer());
                }

            raf.writeChars(ch);
            raf.seek(0);
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row){
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; ++col) {
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any code that you have atempted? If so, could you post it? And, I would go about this by using a `while()` loop.

Comment: just included my code

Comment: What is preventing you from reading entire file into string, parse it there with say regex, and then store it into file ?

Comment: I keep getting an error when I do Integer.ParseInt(). How would I find all the letters when seek() is for int? @user3360241 Sorry it seem like im asking a lot, but im mentally exhausted from finals and I cant even think straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing for-loop (j < raf.length) with a while loop with the following contents:

```
long currPointer = 0;
while(currPointer < raf.length()) {
  long currPointer = raf.getFilePointer(); // save current cursor position
  char currentChar = raf.readChar(); // read current char

  if (currentChar == letter) { // if char equals that to be replaced
     raf.seek(currPointer); // step cursor one step back
     raf.writeChar(ch); // replace char
  }

  currPointer = raf.getFilePointer() // store the position of the cursor 

}
```

**EDIT**: now the file is traversed character by character, as opposed to byte by byte. Given that various character encodings may not use a constant number of bytes per character, this is the easiest approach.

Basically:

```
LOOP through all characters in file
    IF current character equals that to be replaced
         step cursor back by one (otherwise you'd be overwriting the next character)
         replace character
```

Just out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to achieve with:

```
raf.seek((raf.length()-1)*2);
```

Comment: I was trying to get it to where the user could enter an odd number. before i had: raf.seek(position). It would seek in two's because I used char and that is two bytes.

Comment: I changed the solution to not traverse the file byte by byte as different encodings may use different byte sizes for characters (Java internal representation does not necessarily equal file representation). I would suggest you use some sort of IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ) and step through this code to make sure it reads char by char, and compares them correctly.

Comment: Your code worked! I had to fix some errors in it, but after that my program works great! Thanks so much